# How to get the compressed representation generated by the autoencoder?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, autoencoder, encoder

I'm making a deep multimodal autoencoder which takes two inputs and produces a two outputs (which are the reconstructed inputs). The two inputs are with shape of (1000, 50) and (1000,60) respectively and the model has 3 hidden layers and aim to concatenate the two latent layer of input1 and input2.

here is the complete code of the model :

```
input_X = Input(shape=(X[0].shape))

dense_X = Dense(40,activation='relu')(input_X)

dense1_X = Dense(20,activation='relu')(dense_X)

latent_X= Dense(2,activation='relu')(dense1_X)

input_X1 = Input(shape=(X1[0].shape))

dense_X1 = Dense(40,activation='relu')(input_X1)

dense1_X1 = Dense(20,activation='relu')(dense_X1)

latent_X1= Dense(2,activation='relu')(dense1_X1)

Concat_X_X1 = concatenate([latent_X, latent_X1])

decoding_X = Dense(20,activation='relu')(Concat_X_X1)

decoding1_X = Dense(40,activation='relu')(decoding_X)

output_X = Dense(X[0].shape[0],activation='sigmoid')(decoding1_X)

decoding_X1 = Dense(20,activation='relu')(Concat_X_X1)

decoding1_X1 = Dense(40,activation='relu')(decoding_X1)

output_X1 = Dense(X1[0].shape[0],activation='sigmoid')(decoding1_X1)

multi_modal_autoencoder = Model([input_X, input_X1], [output_X, output_X1], name='multi_modal_autoencoder')

encoder = Model([input_X, input_X1], Concat_X_X1)

encoder.save('encoder.h5')

multi_modal_autoencoder.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001),loss='mse')

model = multi_modal_autoencoder.fit([X,X1], [X, X1], epochs=70, batch_size=150)
```

I would like to return the latent representation from the encoder which would behave as a numpy array with the shape of (1000,4) to use it then as input to another model. Hope, someone with that knowledge helps me to achieve it. To do so, i tried the following as suggested :

```
file = h5py.File('encoder.h5', 'r')
keys = list(file.keys())   #it returns models weights as key
value = file.get('model_weights') #<HDF5 group "/model_weights" (9 members)> 
the 9 members are ['concatenate_1', 'dense_1', 'dense_2', 'dense_3', 'dense_4',        'dense_5', 'dense_6', 'input_1', 'input_2'].
```

```
file['/model_weights/concatenate_1']) returns <HDF5 group "/model_weights/concatenate_1" (0 members)>
value = file['/model_weights/concatenate_1'][:]
```

But it returns an error :

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-7bc6cbac9468> in <module>
----> 1 value = file['/model_weights/concatenate_1'][:]

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\group.py in __getitem__(self, name)
    260                 raise ValueError("Invalid HDF5 object reference")
    261         else:
--> 262             oid = h5o.open(self.id, self._e(name), lapl=self._lapl)
    263 
    264         otype = h5i.get_type(oid)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\base.py in _e(self, name, lcpl)
    135         else:
    136             try:
--> 137                 name = name.encode('ascii')
    138                 coding = h5t.CSET_ASCII
    139             except UnicodeEncodeError:

AttributeError: 'slice' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `X[0].shape[0]` and `X1[0].shape[0]` are equal and since it is a dense layer it should be 4000. You have already managed to get to the training phase, but better I say that return value of  `Model.fit` is a history object of achieved losses during training. Your object named `model` is then actually not a model.

To predict values with this trained model, you need to call `Model.predict()`, in your case should look like:

```
multi_modal_autoencoder.predict([D1,D2])
```

`Model.predict()` returns numpy array(s) of predictions, two arrays in your case and probably reshape method will be in need after retrieving your predictions for the input. You can then use this output as an input for the next network.

I strongly encourage you to read the [docs](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/)

Comment: Yes, it is thanks to your help. Just another matter of comprehension, because I finally find someone expert in machine learning and i want to take advantage of your experience. I already edited my question, can you please take a look?

Comment: @in case it works, please accept the answer, the new problems that appear should be asked in new question if you are unable to solve it, as it targets a different problem

Comment: You really do have it right, please excuse my mistake.

Comment: @Florida I actually have no idea why you load saved model but I believe you should work with the sequential representation `model = load_model('model.h5')` and then use  `model.predict()` to get the output
do not forget to add `from keras.models import load_model`

Comment: It worked, thank you i really value the help you've given me.